# Spring 5 Migration: How to add the suffix .do to all RequestMappings?

Tags: java, spring

I'm migrating a Spring Project from v4.30 with Java 8 to v5.3.x with Java 11 (NOT Spring Boot).

All our RequestMappings used the suffix .do via Configuration, the endpoint in this class

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeWebController 
    @GetMapping("welcome") public String welcome() { ... } // -> welcome.do
    @GetMapping("hello")   public String hello()   { ... } // -> hello.do
```

was actually a welcome.do or a hello.do, although the `@GetMapping("welcome")` has no ".do".

We configured this suffix (among others) in a Spring derived configuration class like that:

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer extends AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
      return new String[] { "*.do", "*.xyz", "/webresources/*" };
    }
```

This worked fine in Spring4, but no longer in Spring 5 (although the debugger stops at `getServletMappings`).

A possible workaround would be to add the .do to all RequestMappings,

```
@GetMapping(value={"welcome","welcome.do"})
```

but I think, there's a better way, as we have 100+ endpoints.

Reading along, I think the way to go in Spring 5 is to derive from WebMvcConfigurer like that:

```
public class MyWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        // Should I use setPathMatcher or setPatternParser? Or am I completely wrong here?
        // Is configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(true) relevant here?
```

That's where I'm struggling, I don't quite get how to use it.
How do I override this method? Is this the right place to add the suffix?
Or can I somehow continue to use my old `MyWebAppInitializer` (see above) with the servlet mappings?

Thanks

Comment: You ofcourse did read the migration guides for all the versions you skipped? Which would have lead you to https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-controller/ann-requestmapping.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-suffix-pattern-match. Which explains what to do. In short do `configurer. useSuffixPatternMatching(true);` (as the default is `false`).

Comment: You're right, thanks. Something of note: I had in my code
`configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(true);``configurer.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(true);`
and it didn't work. Removing the latter and it works.

Comment: The one you used requires explicit setting of the suffixes that are supported and is used in conjuction with content negotiation.